# Sound only plays on iOS when another video is playing

Tags: ios, reactjs, audio, next.js, usesound

I'm using the use-sound/React Component https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound to play a sound file inside a next.js stack. This works fine - except on iPhones/iOS. There it's a strange behavior.

you klick on the Start-Sound-Button, nothing happens. On the site there is a video, followed by some text a this Sound-Button. If the video is playing und you click on the Sound-Button, the sound starts as well!

```
 const ListenStory = ({ soundFile, soundAuthor }: Props) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
  const [play, { stop }] = useSound(soundFile, { volume: 0.4 })
  const [isMobile, isPad, cacheBuster] = useIsMobile()

 function playSong() {
setIsPlaying(true)
play()
}

 function stopSong() {
setIsPlaying(false)
stop()
}
```

....

```
<div className={styles.playBtn} onClick={isPlaying ? stopSong : playSong}>
          <p className={styles.listenTitle}>Listen</p>
        </div>
```

Any ideas where I can solve this strange behavior? Thanks

Comment: Does the behaviour change if the _silent mode_ toggle switch is flipped?

Comment: no, same behavior